# Can VPN hardware provide adequate isolation on a home network?

Tags: vpn, threat-mitigation

If you were to configure a Work PC at home to exclusively connect to your work network via a small VPN box, would this adequately isolate it from your home network and related threats?

What alternatives would you recommend?

Work PC <=cable=> VPN Hardware <=cable/wifi=> Home Router <=> Work VPN Endpoint

Comment: You should define what you would consider adequate isolation, and include a fair bit about the behavior of your VPN box.

Comment: Depending on the routing/firewall rules on the dedicated VPN box, your work computer still may be able to connect to devices on your home network.

Comment: I'm assuming that the VPN and laptop are preconfigured with firewall rules (not dependant on the home router firewall)

Comment: The goal here is to ship home a preconfigured laptop or PC with preconfigured VPN Hardware to act as a firewall between the local LAN and the remote VPN'd network without requiring the user to configure their home router.

Comment: What would an extra box add, that a software VPN solution on the laptop would not?

Comment: The ability to exclude the PC network port from connecting to the local LAN (since it only connects to the hardware VPN).  Bear in mind this is for non-techies to take home and use. I'm sure know *you* know how to avoid this - but non-techies need preconfigured components and *simple* instructions. Ideally the VPN device would need cable connection at PC end and wifi to connect to router.

Answer (score 1):

A properly configured VPN hardware box can provide in this setup appropriate protection for the Work PC from attacks originating in the local LAN. It will also protect against attacks against the VPN tunnel from the internet. It will also protect your LAN against attacks starting from the Work PC.

It will not protect against attacks which start after the VPN endpoint, i.e. from inside the work or from the internet which is able to reach the VPN endpoint. Specifically the VPN alone will not magically protect against malicious websites you visit on the Work PC or malicious mails. These threats are commonly handled by some security product located between the VPN endpoint and the internet but these products will not provide perfect protection.

Your VPN setup will also not protect against physical access of the Work PC by others.

Comment: Yes I understand that. Any work place has those risks. In this instance the laptop would be preconfigured with SOE of the workplace including the usual AV protection.

Comment: I aware of the physical access issue.